# Read a specific row in a csv file and check for an input match

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to check that an ID matches when an input is made in a command line argument. I want the input to be checked against the ID that is in the csv file. Here is a sample command line argument that gets put in when a person wants to check their file for inputs. They need to input the correct id and the correct path to their file. The id and the path must match in order for the script to run. I have the path input working fine already.

```
$ python filename.py CA-BB-CD /etc/pathtofile/myfile.csv 

Action   Object Type         ID  
Add       Service          CA-BB-CC 
Add       Service Team     CA-BB-CC
Modify    Host Team        CA-BB-CC
Modify    Service Team     CA-BB-CC
```

What I have in my code now:

```
#!usr/bin/python

from subprocess import *
import sys
import ConfigParser
import os
import csv
import getopt
import time
import datetime
import logging
from sys import argv
script, input_id, input_file = argv

#set up logging to file
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S',
                filename='/etc/pathtofile/mydirectory/logs/mylog.log',
                filemode='w')
# defining a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# setting a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# telling the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# adding the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

#set up configuration Parser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('/etc/mypath/ingestion/objectItems.cfg')
config.read('/etc/mypath/ingestion/action.cfg')

#get objects
objects = config.get('Objects', 'objects')

#get actions
actions = config.get('Actions', 'actions')

#if no object is found, run error
assert(sys.argv[1] != None), "object does not exist"
#logging debug 
#logging.debug('object does not exist')

#Get inputs and check value and path to file
def print_all(f):
    f.read()

def input_id(r):
    r.read()


# place an exception for incorrect path
try:
    current_file = open(input_file)
    print_all(current_file)

    current_input = open(input_file(row[3]))
    input_id(current_input)

#list exceptions  
except IOError:
    print("No such file or directory. Please try again")
#logging error
logging.error('No such file or directory. Please try again')
except IOError:
print("Solution id is invalid. Please check the number and try again")
#logging error
logging.error('Solution id is invalid. Please check the number and try again') 
except IOError:
print("Undefined action found")
#logging warning 
logging.warning('Undefined action found') 
close
```

Comment: have you tried using the `csv` module?

Comment: No I haven't I am importing it already.

Comment: why not read up on the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) in the docs and give it a go? *Then* post your code and a question if you run into trouble. You would learn a lot more.

Comment: Okay I went over the csv module and updated my code. I have the csv in place and the file is being read but my input value is not giving me an error like it should when the wrong one is put in.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding a for loop.
Here is my code:

```
#!usr/bin/python


from subprocess import *
import sys
import ConfigParser
import os
import csv
import getopt
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date
from time import gmtime, strftime
import logging
from sys import argv
script, solution_id, input_file = argv

#creating time stamp and returning as a string to add to solution id log name
def timeIzNow():  
    full = time.strftime(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    return full

#set up logging to file
LOG_FILENAME = solution_id  + timeIzNow() 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s %(process)d',
                    datefmt='%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', 
                    filename=LOG_FILENAME,
              filemode='w')   
# defining a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# setting a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# telling the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# adding the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

#set up configuration Parser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('/etc/nagios/ingestion/objectItems.cfg')
config.read('/etc/nagios/ingestion/action.cfg')

#get objects
objects = config.get('Objects', 'objects')

#get actions
actions = config.get('Actions', 'actions')

#if no object is found, run error
assert(sys.argv[1] != None), "object does not exist"

#logging debug 
#logging.debug('object does not exist')

#Get inputs and check value and path to file


try:
    f = csv.reader(open(input_file, "rb")) 
except:
    logging.error('No such file or directory. Please try again')   
else:
    try:  
        for row in f:            
            if solution_id != row[2]:
                print "Solution ID is invalid. Pleae check the number and try again"
    except ValueError: 
                logging.error('Solution ID is invalid. Please check the number and try again') 
    else:
        print row     







finally: 
     print "all error checks done!"

# let's do add update delete. that way we don't have to do a conversion in the script from modify to update
# uSE THE CODE THAT i'M USING TO VALIDATE
```